# .NET MVC3 - reading HTML parts from XML and showing in razor view

Tags: .net, html, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to show some text and image data (which are in html markup) into a Razor view from a XML file. for example I have the following Xml:

```
<newsitems>
    <news id="1">
         <body>
             <p>lorem ipsum <h2>dolor</h2>.</p>
         </body>
    </news>
</newsitems>
```

then I need to show that inner html into a view. please show me the best way and code if possible! thx.

Answer (score 3):

Create a view model (which is just a fancy name for a class used to represent data in a well-understood, structured way) in the `Models` directory of your MVC application, if you have one, such as:

```
public class NewsItemViewModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Create an action in your controller to extract instances of `NewsItemViewModel` from the XML. I'd use LINQ-to-XML. Let's assume you have a controller named `NewsController` in your `Controllers` directory.

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // replace XElement.Parse(...) below to your own routine to load the XML file
        var newsItems = (from news in XElement.Parse(@"<newsitems>
<news id=""1"">
     <body>
         <p>lorem ipsum <h2>dolor</h2>.</p>
     </body>
</news>
  </newsitems>").Descendants("news")
         let body = news.Descendants("body").First()
         select new NewsItemViewModel {Id = (int)news.Attribute("id"), Body = body.Value });

        return View(newsItems);
    }
}
```

Now create a view for `NewsController.Index` (following my example, that'd be `Views/News/Index.cshtml`).

```
@model IEnumerable<YourApplicationNameSpace.Models.NewsItemViewModel>

@foreach(var newsItem in Model)
{
      <div class="newsitem">
       @Html.Raw(newsItem.Body)
      </div>
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. I assume you are the author of the XML, or otherwise trust the source of the XML. If you don't, I would consider preprocessing the `NewsItemViewModel.Body` property to strip potentially dangerous HTML or script to prevent malicious content from breaking your site or worse.
2. Wrap the HTML content in the `body` node of each `news` element in your XML in [`CDATA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) so that the HTML content does not break your XML file and thus the ability to successfully parse it.